# how to change the color and fontsize of X-axis coordinate value in google line chart

Tags: google-visualization

Hi iam working on google chart it is displaying fine but i need the font size and color of the text displayed on X-axis and Y-axis coordines.Can any one tell how to do this one

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hAxis.textStyle.color` and vAxis.textStyle.color` options to set the color of the axis labels.

Answer (score 0):

Use the textStyleOption to set the color to labels.

hAxis: {
        title: "Locations",
        textStyle: {
              color: 'black'
        }
  },